# Vba code to copy all rows having index i of for loop where i is based on if condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing a problem in the below VBA code, My requirement is to copy some rows from one worksheet and paste it in to another worksheet but those rows are based on condition, My below code only copy the last row of the condition met so kindly help me with the code or suggest different approach of doing the same.

```
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastrow
    If IsNumeric(Range("B" & i)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) = False And Range("B" & i) <> 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).Select
        Row(i).Copy
        'For j = i To Lastrow
        '    If IsNumeric(Range("C" & j)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("C" & j)) = False And Range("C" & j) <> 0 Then
        '        MsgBox (j)
        '    End If
        'Next j
    End If
Next i
```

In the above-mentioned code What I want that code select and copy each I row index of condition met instead of only last row index of condition met.

Comment: You have not posted a very clear & complete code. Destination where row would be copied is unclear. Also while posting the code make sure you indent correctly so that it appears correctly on the site.

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of it from the next time and need to work on rows and cell on the same sheet where the condition is being checked. and I have not written further code so able to share it only the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to copy all the cells where your criteria is met, you can define a `Range` object, in my code below it's `CopyRng`, and every time your criteria is met, you use the `Union` function to add the current cell to `CopyRng`.

So at the end, you can copy all cells where the criteria is met by using `CopyRng.Copy`.

***Code***

```
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If IsNumeric(.Range("B" & i)) And Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value) <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> 0 Then
            If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Range("B" & i))
            Else
                Set CopyRng = .Range("B" & i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    CopyRng.Copy
End With
```

---

**Edit 1**: copy the entire row where the criteria is met (modify only the inner `If` part)

```
If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
    Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Rows(i))
Else
    Set CopyRng = .Rows(i)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This one I want :)

Comment: @yashikavaish your'e welcome :) now comes your part, where you mark as "ANSWER" by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)

Comment: @yashikavaish it seems you have posted many question on this site, but never found the time to give proper feedback and give users the credit for helping you (such as marking as answer), this could hurt your chances of getting more help here in the future...

Comment: Ya sure I do, Could you please suggest if in the same code I want the complete row to be pasted instead of that cell that meets a condition so what changes do I need to do.

Comment: @yashikavaish this sounds like a good new post here. As for this post, and the question you raised, you should close with this answer. So future users who are seeking help with a similar issue will be able to find the solution they are looking for.

Comment: I always do initially I am not aware of this thing that It is also necessary to mark the suitable answer so maybe I missed it

Comment: @yashikavaish so now you do, you can start with this post, and go back to previous posts who had here, and give credit to other users who assisted you

Comment: But In my question It is stated that copying of all rows that met criteria so This is the part of the question, and I am really grateful if you can suggest me :)

Comment: @yashikavaish the answer copies all of them. You don't mention in your post, or code, where do you want to paste them

Comment: Ya that's fine but I am talking about coying complete row of index I instead of copying that cell, I am not saying to suggest me with paste code that I will do just I am facing the problem in copying part, The code you have given copying the cells not complete rows

Comment: Thank you so much, @Shai Rado It works that exactly I want :)